# Nginx directory listing is enabled, but I not see all files

Tags: nginx

everyone. I have several symbolic links to logs in separate folder.

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Sep 28 14:00 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Sep 28 12:34 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   38 Sep 28 13:24 default.access.log -> /path/to/default/access/log
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   37 Sep 28 13:24 default.error.log -> /path/to/default/error/log
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   26 Sep 28 14:00 fpm.error.log -> /path/to/php/fpm/error/log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   50 Sep 28 13:50 .htpasswd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   37 Sep 28 13:24 images.access.log -> /path/to/images/access/log;
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   36 Sep 28 13:24 images.error.log -> /path/to/images/error/log;
```

I want to see this files through url. My nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name servername;

    root /path/to/root;
    charset UTF-8;

    access_log /path/to/access/log;
    error_log /path/to/error/log;

    location ~ \.htpasswd$ {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~* \.log$ {
        expires epoch;
        log_not_found off;
        add_header  Content-Type    text/plain;
        auth_basic  "Restricted";
        auth_basic_user_file    /path/to/htpasswd;
    }

    location  /  {
        autoindex  on;
        auth_basic  "Restricted";
        auth_basic_user_file    /path/to/htpasswd;
    }
}
```

It works correctly, but I see only four files:

```
default.access.log        28-Sep-2013 14:19        3431596
default.error.log         28-Sep-2013 13:40            728
images.access.log         28-Sep-2013 14:18         415324
images.error.log          28-Sep-2013 12:05              0
```

Where is my mistake? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you make sure nginx user can read the missing file?

```
fpm.error.log -> /path/to/php/fpm/error/log
```

Notice that it will need read permission for all the parent paths as well.

Comment: `[root@server php-fpm]# ls -la error.log 
-rw------- 1 nginx root 734 Sep 28 18:02 error.log`

Answer (score 0):

This is super old but in case anyone else comes along this can also be caused by SELinux or apparmour if your labels are not set right.  Quick test to setenforce 0 if  you can.  Otherwise make sure labels are right.

```
sudo chcon -Rt httpd_sys_content_t /your/path
```